Proving $\frac{a+1}{a^2+3} +\frac{b+1}{b^2+3} \ge \frac{c-1}{c^2+3} + \frac{d-1}{d^2+3}$ for real $a,b,c,d$ such that $ab(c+d)=cd(a+b)$
The problem states :

Let $a, b, c, d$ be real numbers, such that $ab(c+d)=cd(a+b)$.
Prove that $\frac{a+1}{a^2+3}+\frac{b+1}{b^2+3} \geq \frac{c-1}{c^2+3}+\frac{d-1}{d^2+3}$.

Source. This problem is from the contest "Stars of Mathematics" , 2022 , question 3 for seniors.
First of all , I think it is quite weird that $a,b,c,d$ are real numbers , not necessarily positive ones.
Moving on from this little side note , this is the progress I've made so far :
$$ab(c+d)=cd(a+b) \iff \frac{1}{a} + \frac{1}{b} = \frac{1}{c} + \frac{1}{d}$$
I tried proving that : $LHS \ge \frac{1}{a}+\frac{1}{b}=\frac{1}{c}+\frac{1}{d} \ge RHS$ , which obviously holds for  $a,b \in (3,+\infty)$ and $c,d \in (-3,+\infty)$.
I also tried doing this with something like Jensen's inequality or Majorization Inequality , but the second derivative of the function is absolutely insane , and impossible to find out on what interval the function $f(x)=\frac{x+1}{x^2+3}$ is convex or concave.
Any help/hints or even full solutions are much appreciated.

There is - sign on the right and + on the left numerator?

after $a,b,c,d \to \frac 1a, \frac 1b, \frac 1c, \frac 1d$ and then $c,d\to -c, -d,$ and letting $f(x) = \dfrac{x^2+x}{3x^2+1}$, your inequality is equivalent to :
$$f(a)+f(b)+f(c)+f(d)\geq 0$$
if $a+b+c+d=0.$ This is trivial for the regions where $f$ is convex due to Jensen's. Not sure about the concave regions.

Another way: If $abcd=0$ (easy). If $abcd \ne 0$, letting $x := \frac{1}{a}, y := \frac{1}{b}, u := \frac{1}{c}, v := \frac{1}{d}$, it suffices to prove that, for all $x, y, u, v \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x + y = u + v$,
$$\frac{x+x^2}{1+3x^2} + \frac{y+y^2}{1+3y^2} \ge \frac{u-u^2}{1+3u^2} + \frac{v-v^2}{1+3v^2}. $$ Let $p := x + y = u + v$. For any fixed $p \in \mathbb{R}$, we can obtain a closed form of both $\min\limits_{x+y = p} \frac{x+x^2}{1+3x^2} + \frac{y+y^2}{1+3y^2} $ and $\max\limits_{u+v=p} \frac{u-u^2}{1+3u^2} + \frac{v-v^2}{1+3v^2}$. (I noticed that @nonuser has tried this way.)

Thanks a lot ! Could you go a little bit more into detail ? I don't understand the last part fully .

@RabelCapdemiel You may use @, otherwise I may not receive the notification. It is not a contest style solution. So wait for a contest style solution.

@RiverLi Ok , thanks for telling me . I'm new to MSE .

@RiverLi I also thought of that and then looked at Lagrange multiplier which gave a messy equation so I gave up. I think you should still post a solution if you have it.

@dezdichado The form is good: Let $$m(p) := \min_{x + y = p} \left(\frac{x+x^2}{1+3x^2} + \frac{y+y^2}{1+3y^2}\right). $$ Then
$$m(p) = \left{\begin{array}{ll}
\frac{2(2p+p^2)}{4+3p^2} & \frac23 - \frac83 \cos \frac{2\pi}{9} \le p \le \frac23 -\frac83 \cos\frac{4\pi}{9} \[6pt]
\frac{1}{3p} + \frac12 - \frac19\sqrt{9 + \frac{12}{p^2}} & \mathrm{otherwise}.
\end{array}
\right.$$

@RiverLi that is nice! It looks like min is attained at $x=y=\frac p2$ in that small range. What are these values for the other range ?

@dezdichado I use Mathematica to get it. Since it is a closed form, I think one can do it by hand. Anyway, it is not a contest style solution. We are seeking the contest style solution. Can we use trigonometric substitution?

@dezdichado We can also use the pqr method along your comment. Let $p = a + b + c, q = ab + bc + ca, r =a bc$. It suffices to prove that $$ \left( 108,{p}^{2}-27,p+27 \right) {r}^{2}+ \left( -54,{p}^{3}+27
,{p}^{2}q-9,{p}^{2}-12,p+9,q-9 \right) r$$ $$+6,{p}^{4}+9,{p}^{3}q+27
,{p}^{2}{q}^{2}-12,{p}^{2}q-9,p{q}^{2}+2,{p}^{2}+9,pq+6,{q}^{2}-
2,q
\ge 0.$$ (note that which is quadratic in $r$) However, there is much work (by hand) to get the pqr expression and prove the above (and hence not a contest style solution).

@RiverLi I definitely used to be able to brute force a couple pages of $pqr$ solution during contest. But I agree about this particular one, specifically because it is very non-homogeneous.

@dezdichado Yes. By the way, sometimes, when it is a sum of $N$ rational functions such as $\sum _i \frac{f_i}{g_i}$, after full expanding,  even $N$ is small, the expression can be very long, e.g. $\frac{x_1}{4x_2+1} + \frac{x_2}{4x_3+1} + \frac{x_3}{4x_4+1} + \frac{x_4}{4x_5+1} + \frac{x_5}{4x_1+1} + \frac{1}{x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4+x_5} \ge \frac65$ (although in the OP, it is not very long due to four terms).

If $ab(c+d)=cd(a+b)$ then $a,b$ and $c,d$ are symmetrical and have small values, the series of $\frac{x\pm 1}{x^2+3}$ proofs which is greater based on how small $x$ is, $x\in {a,b,c,d}$

My second solution.
If $abcd=0$, true (easy).
If $abcd\ne 0$, according to @dezdichado's comment on the OP, it suffices to prove that, for all $a, b, c, d\in \mathbb{R}$ with $a + b + c + d = 0$,
$$\frac{a^2 + a}{3a^2 + 1}
+ \frac{b^2 + b}{3b^2 + 1} + \frac{c^2 + c}{3c^2 + 1}
+ \frac{d^2 + d}{3d^2 + 1} \ge 0,$$
or (using $\frac{a^2 + a}{3a^2 + 1} + \frac16 = \frac{(3a+1)^2}{6(3a^2 + 1)}$)
$$\frac{(3a+1)^2}{6(3a^2 + 1)} + \frac{(3a+1)^2}{6(3a^2 + 1)}
+ \frac{(3a+1)^2}{6(3a^2 + 1)} + \frac{(3a+1)^2}{6(3a^2 + 1)} \ge \frac23. \tag{1}$$
Let $x := 3a + 1, y := 3b + 1, z := 3c + 1, w := 3d + 1$. It suffices to prove that, for all $x, y, z, w \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x + y + z + w = 4$,
$$\frac{x^2}{x^2-2x+4} + \frac{y^2}{y^2-2y+4}
+ \frac{z^2}{z^2-2z+4} + \frac{w^2}{w^2-2w+4} \ge \frac43. \tag{2}$$
@dezdichado's elegant proof of (2): We have
$$\frac{x^2}{x^2-2x+4}
= \frac{4x^2}{4x^2-8x+16}=  \frac{4x^2}{3x^2 + (4 - x)^2} 
= \frac{4x^2}{3x^2 + (y+z+w)^2}$$
$$\ge \frac{4x^2}{3x^2 + 3(y^2 + z^2 + w^2)} = \frac43 \cdot \frac{x^2}{x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2}.$$
Thus, (2) is true.
$\phantom{2}$

My proof of (2)
By Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz inequality, it suffices to prove that
$$\frac{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2)^2}{x^2(x^2 - 2x + 4) + y^2(y^2 - 2y + 4) + z^2(z^2 - 2z + 4) + w^2(w^2 - 2w + 4)} \ge \frac43,$$
or
$$\frac{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2)^2}{(x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + w^4) - 2(x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + w^3) + 4(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2)} \ge \frac43. \tag{3}$$
(3) is written as (homogenization)
$$\frac{(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2)^2}{(x^4 + y^4 + z^4 + w^4) - 2(x^3 + y^3 + z^3 + w^3)Q + 4(x^2 + y^2 + z^2 + w^2)Q^2} \ge \frac43 \tag{4}$$
where $Q := (x + y + z + w)/4$.
Since (4) is homogeneous, WLOG, assume that $w = 1$. Then we use the pqr method.
Let $p := x + y + z, q := xy + yz + zx, r := xyz$. (4) is equivalent to
$$(-5p+3)r+2p^2-pq+2q^2-5q \ge 0. \tag{5}$$
(5) is true. The rest is smooth.
Hope to see a nice proof of (3).

Your setup and my first post are the same, except for factor of 2. IDK, but x+y+z+w=2, g(x) = x^2/(x^2-x+1) may help.

@albertchan Yes, I think some other users may try similar setup. I think the Cauchy-Bunyakovsky-Schwarz idea in my answer is also usual in contest inequality proving (but I did not go this way some days ago, my first answer is more complicated).

@RiverLi how about:
$$\dfrac{4x^2}{4x^2-8x+16} = \dfrac{4x^2}{3x^2+(y+z+w)^2}\geq\dfrac{4x^2}{3(x^2+y^2+z^2+w^2)}$$ ?

@dezdichado WOW, elegant!

Warning. This is not a contest style solution. Here we want to give a solution including no calculus (although we used calculus to motivate our solution).
If $abcd = 0$, it is true (easy).
If $abcd \ne 0$, letting $x := \frac{1}{a}, y := \frac{1}{b}, u := \frac{1}{c}, v := \frac{1}{d}$, it suffices to prove that, for all $x, y, u, v \in \mathbb{R}$ with $x + y = u + v$,
$$\frac{x+x^2}{1+3x^2} + \frac{y+y^2}{1+3y^2} \ge \frac{u-u^2}{1+3u^2} + \frac{v-v^2}{1+3v^2}. \tag{1}$$
Since (1) does not change if we replace $x, y, u, v$ with $-u, -v, -x, -y$ respectively, WLOG, assume that $x + y\ge 0$.
We split into three cases.

Case 1. $x + y \ge 2$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{x+x^2}{1+3x^2} + \frac{y+y^2}{1+3y^2} \ge \frac16 
\ge \frac{u-u^2}{1+3u^2} + \frac{v-v^2}{1+3v^2}. \tag{2}$$
The proof of (2) is given at the end.
Thus, (1) is true.

Case 2. $\frac43 < x + y < 2$

It suffices to prove that
$$\frac{x+x^2}{1+3x^2} + \frac{y+y^2}{1+3y^2} \ge \frac14 
\ge \frac{u-u^2}{1+3u^2} + \frac{v-v^2}{1+3v^2}. \tag{3}$$
The proof of (3) is given at the end.
Thus, (1) is true.

Case 3. $0 \le x + y \le \frac43$

It suffices to prove that
$$2 \cdot \frac{\frac{u+v}{2} - (\frac{u+v}{2})^2}{1 + 3(\frac{u+v}{2})^2} \ge \frac{u-u^2}{1+3u^2} +  \frac{v-v^2}{1+3v^2}, \tag{4}$$
and
$$\frac{x+x^2}{1+3x^2} + \frac{y+y^2}{1+3y^2} \ge 2 \cdot \frac{\frac{x+y}{2} - (\frac{x+y}{2})^2}{1 + 3(\frac{x+y}{2})^2}. \tag{5}$$
The proof of (4) and (5) is given at the end.
From (4) and (5), (1) is true.
In summary, we are done.
$\phantom{2}$

Proof of (2).
WLOG, assume that $x \ge y$ and $u \ge v$.
Then $x \ge 1$ and $u \ge 1$.
We have
$$
\frac{x+x^2}{1+3x^2} + \frac{y+y^2}{1+3y^2} = \frac16 + \frac{3x - 1}{3(1+3x^2)} + \frac{(3y+1)^2}{6(1+3y^2)} \ge \frac16,
$$
and
$$\frac{u-u^2}{1+3u^2} + \frac{v-v^2}{1+3v^2}
\le \frac{v-v^2}{1+3v^2}
= \frac16 - \frac{(3v-1)^2}{6(1+3v^2)} \le \frac16.$$

Proof of (3).
We have
\begin{align*}
 &60(1+3x^2)(1+3y^2)\left(\frac{x+x^2}{1+3x^2} + \frac{y+y^2}{1+3y^2} - \frac14\right) \\
 ={}& (15xy + 6x + 6y - 1)^2 - 21(x+y)^2 + 72(x+y)-16\\
 \ge{}& - 21(x+y)^2 + 72(x+y)-16\\
 >{}& 0.
\end{align*}
Also, we have
\begin{align*}
 &132(1+3u^2)(1+3v^2)\left(\frac14 - \frac{u-u^2}{1+3u^2} - \frac{v-v^2}{1+3v^2}\right)\\
 ={}& (-33uv+6u+6v+7)^2+195(u+v)^2-216(u+v)-16\\
 \ge{}& 195(u+v)^2-216(u+v)-16\\
 >{}& 0. 
\end{align*}

Proof of (4).
We have
\begin{align*}
 &2 \cdot \frac{\frac{u+v}{2} - (\frac{u+v}{2})^2}{1 + 3(\frac{u+v}{2})^2} - \frac{u-u^2}{1+3u^2} - \frac{v-v^2}{1+3v^2}\\
 ={}& \frac{-3(u+v)^2 + 9(u+v) + 2 - uv(6 + 9u +9v)}{(1+3u^2)(1+3v^2)(4+3(u+v)^2)}(u-v)^2\\
 \ge{}& \frac{-3(u+v)^2 + 9(u+v) + 2 - \frac{(u+v)^2}{4}(6 + 9u +9v)}{(1+3u^2)(1+3v^2)(4+3(u+v)^2)}(u-v)^2\\
 \ge{} & 0 \tag{4}
\end{align*}
where we use $uv \le \frac{(u+v)^2}{4}$,
and $-3(u+v)^2 + 9(u+v) + 2 - \frac{(u+v)^2}{4}(6 + 9u +9v) \ge 0$ for all $0 \le u + v \le \frac43$.

Proof of (5).
Let $p := x + y$, $q := xy$, and $Q := p^2 - 4q \ge 0$. We have
\begin{align*}
 &\frac{x+x^2}{1+3x^2} + \frac{y+y^2}{1+3y^2} - 2 \cdot \frac{\frac{x+y}{2} - (\frac{x+y}{2})^2}{1 + 3(\frac{x+y}{2})^2}\\
 ={}& \frac{(36p^2-36p+24)q^2+(9p^3-18p^2+36p-8)q+9p^4-9p^3+6p^2}{(1+3x^2)(1+3y^2)(4 + 3(x+y)^2)}\\
 ={}& \frac{ (9p^2-9p+6)Q^2 + (-18p^4+9p^3+6p^2-36p+8)Q+9p^6+24p^4+16p^2
 }{4(1+3x^2)(1+3y^2)(4 + 3(x+y)^2)}\\
 \ge{}& \frac{ 2\sqrt{(9p^2-9p+6)(9p^6+24p^4+16p^2)}\,Q + (-18p^4+9p^3+6p^2-36p+8)Q
 }{4(1+3x^2)(1+3y^2)(4 + 3(x+y)^2)}\\
 \ge{}& 0
\end{align*}
where we use AM-GM, and
$2\sqrt{(9p^2-9p+6)(9p^6+24p^4+16p^2)} + (-18p^4+9p^3+6p^2-36p+8)\ge 0$ for all $p\in \mathbb{R}$.

Starting from first comment by dezdichado, with same setup.
Given: $a + b + c + d = 0$
$f(x) = \frac{x^2+x}{3x^2+1}$
Proof: $f(a) + f(b) + f(c) + f(d) ≥ 0$
Solve for $f'(x)=0$, we have $\min (f(x)) = f(-1/3) = -1/6$
The goal is pick this valley, as close as possible, to minimize LHS.
Lets shift the minimum to (0,0), and scale to make formula pretty.
$\displaystyle g(x) = 2\,f\left(\frac{2x}{3} -\frac{1}{3}\right) + \frac{1}{3}
= \frac{x^2}{1 - x + x^2}$
Let $a = \frac{2A}{3}-\frac{1}{3},\; 
b = \frac{2B}{3}-\frac{1}{3},\; 
c = \frac{2C}{3}-\frac{1}{3},\;
d = \frac{2D}{3}-\frac{1}{3}$
$D = \frac{3}{2}\left(d+\frac{1}{3} \right) 
= \frac{3}{2}\left(-a-b-c+\frac{1}{3}\right) = 2-(A+B+C)$
Proof adjusted using $\;\displaystyle g(x) = \frac{x^2}{1 - x + x^2}$
$\displaystyle g(A) + g(B) + g(C) + g(2-(A+B+C)) ≥ \frac{4}{3}$
$g'(x) = -\frac{x(x-2)}{(1-x+x^2)^2}\qquad$  --> Extremum at x = 0, 2
$\min(g(x)) = g(0) = 0\quad$  -- this was why g(x) was made.
$\max(g(x)) = g(2) = \frac{4}{3}$
If we have $A=B=C=0 \quad → LHS = 0+0+0+\frac{4}{3} = \frac{4}{3}$
If A moved away from 0, even slightly, we get this:
$g(ε) = ε^2 + ε^3 - ε^5 - ε^6 \;+\; ...$
$g(2-ε) = \frac{4}{3} - \frac{1}{9}ε^2 - \frac{1}{9}ε^3 - \frac{2}{27}ε^4 \;+\; ...$
$g(ε) + g(2-ε) ≈ \frac{4}{3} + \frac{8}{9}ε^2 ≥ \frac{4}{3}$
We can't shift A from 0, without making LHS bigger.

Using generalized mean, we are good even if A,B,C shift together.  g(εA) + g(εB) + g(εC) + g(2-(εA+εB+εC)) - 4/3 ≈ (εA²+εB²+εC²) - ((εA+εB+εC)/3)² = 3M2² - M1² ≥ 2M2² ≥ 0

2*(g(1/2+ε) + g(1/2-ε)) ≈ 4/3 + 32/9 ε² ≥ 4/3 --> 4*g(1/2) = 4/3 also a minimum. Do we have more?

I think I found "contest style" answer.
$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x^2+3} 
= f(0) - f\left(\frac{-3}{x} \right)$
Given: $a+b+c+d=0$
Proof: $S(a,b,c,d) = f(a)+f(b)+f(c)+f(d) ≤ 4f(0) = \frac{4}{3}$
$f(x) + f(-x) - 2\,f(0) = \frac{2}{3+x^2} - \frac{2}{3} ≤ 0$
$⇒S(a,b,-a,-b) ≤ S(0,0,0,0) = \frac{4}{3}$
We like to set ${a,b}$ to 1 anyway, because $max(f) = f(1) = \frac{1}{2}$
(f is increasing from -3 to 1, there is no reason to go beyond peak)
$S(1,1,-1,-1) = 2\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + 2(0) = 1$
$f(-1+x) + f(-1-x) - 2\,f(-1) = \frac{4x^2}{x^4 + 4x^2 + 16} ≥ 0$
Using AM-GM inequality, we can get its maximum.
$\displaystyle \frac{4x^2}{x^4 + 4x^2 + 16} 
= \frac{1}{\frac{x^2}{4} + \frac{4}{x^2} + 1} 
≤ \frac{1}{2\sqrt{\frac{x^2}{4} · \frac{4}{x^2}} + 1} = \frac{1}{3}
$
Maximum occurs when $\frac{x^2}{4} = \frac{4}{x^2}\quad → x = ±2$
Besides trivial $S(0,0,0,0) 
= 4\left(\frac{1}{3}\right)
= \frac{4}{3}$, we have:
$max(S) = S(1,1,1,-3) = 1 + \frac{1}{3} = \frac{4}{3}$

From f(x) identity, we have (f(a)+(f(b)+f(c)+f(d)) + (f(-3/a)+f(-3/b)+f(-3/c)+f(-3/d)) = 4f(0). Proving 1st term ≤ 4f(0), or 2nd term ≥ 0 are equivalent.

Instead of change function to simplify, we can change its arguments!
Let $\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x^2+3}$
Given: $ab\,(c+d) = cd\,(a+b)$
Proof: $f(a) + f(b) + f(-c) + f(-d) ≥ 0$
$\displaystyle f(x) - f(0) = f(x) - \frac{1}{3}
= \frac{3x-x^2}{9+3x^2} -
= \frac{\frac{3}{x}-1}{\left(\frac{3}{x}\right)^2 + 3}
= -f(-3/x)
$
$-f(-3/a) - f(-3/b) - f(3/c) - f(3/d) ≥ -4\,f(0) = -4/3$
Let $A=-3/a, B=-3/b, C=3/c, D=3/d$
Using the same f, we have a simplified version to proof:
Given: $A + B + C + D = 0$
Proof: $\displaystyle f(A) + f(B) + f(C) + f(D) ≤ 4\,f(0) = \frac{4}{3}$

RHS implied LHS is maximized at $A=B=C=0 → D=0$
This local minimum is easily shown with taylor series
$f(x) = \frac{1}{3} + \frac{x}{3} - \frac{x^2}{9} - \frac{x^3}{9} \;+\;...$
Assumed $A,B,C$ all tiny, we estimate with only 2 term taylor series.
$\require{cancel}
f(A) + f(B) + f(C) + f(D) 
≈ \frac{4}{3} + \cancel{\frac{A+B+C+D}{3}} 
- \frac{A^2+B^2+C^2+D^2}{9} ≤ \frac{4}{3}$

Taylor series don't estimate well when we are too far away.
When we reached extremum, slope is zero, not $\frac{x}{3}$
Previous proof does not imply it is the only local minimum.
Solve $f'(x) = -\frac{(x+3)(x-1)}{(x^2+3)^2} = 0$, we have 2 extremums:
$f(\,x≈-3\,) \;≈\; -\frac{1}{6} + \frac{(x+3)^2}{72}\quad$ -- minimum
$f(\,x≈+1\,) \;≈\; +\frac{1}{2} - \frac{(x-1)^2}{8}\quad$ -- maximum
if $A=B=C=1 → D=-3 → LHS = 3\left(\frac{1}{2}\right) + \frac{-1}{6} = \frac{4}{3}$
This is also a local minimum, and can be shown the same way.
Let $α=A-1, β=B-1, γ=C-1, \; δ=-(α+β+γ)$
$f(A) + f(B) + f(C) + f(D) 
≈ \frac{4}{3} 
- \frac{α^2+β^2+γ^2}{8}
+ \frac{δ^2}{72}$
$\frac{δ^2}{72} 
= \frac{1}{8} \left( \frac{α+β+γ}{3} \right)^2
≤ \frac{1}{8} \left( \frac{α^2+β^2+γ^2}{3} \right)
\quad$ Generalized mean inequality
$\frac{δ^2}{72} = \frac{1}{3} \left( \frac{α^2+β^2+γ^2}{8} \right) - ε^2$
$f(A) + f(B) + f(C) + f(D) 
≈ \frac{4}{3} 
- \frac{2}{3} \left( \frac{α^2+β^2+γ^2}{8} \right) - ε^2
≤ \frac{4}{3}
$

Instead of 4 variables to solve (reduced to 3), we might only need 1.
Let's start with my simplified version (my 2nd post)
$\displaystyle f(x) = \frac{x+1}{x^2+3}$
Given: $A + B + C + D = 0$
Proof: $\displaystyle f(A) + f(B) + f(C) + f(D) ≤ 4\,f(0) = \frac{4}{3}$
1st, no need to proof everywhere, within min(f) and max(f) is enough.
Within this range (-3 to 1), curve is strictly increasing.
Going beyond this range just make LHS sum smaller.
It does not matter how the excess is handled.
CAS> f(x) := (x+1)/(x*x+3)

CAS> factor(f(-3-x) + 3*f(1+x/3) - 4/3)
-4*x^2*(x+3)^2 / (3*(x^2+6*x+12)*(x^2+6*x+36))

CAS> factor(f(-3-x) + 2*f(1+x/2) + f(1) - 4/3)
-x^2*(5*x^2+32*x+56) / (6*(x^2+4*x+16)*(x^2+6*x+12))

CAS> factor(f(-3-x) + f(1+x) + 2*f(1) - 4/3)
-x^2*(x+4)^2 / (3*(x^2+2*x+4)*(x^2+6*x+12))

2nd, say D is most negative (we need a negative, so others can be positive)
To maximize LHS, $A=B=C$, because curve is concave down between 0 and 1.
FYI, f''(x) roots are [-4.759, -0.3054, 2.064], negative within last 2 numbers.
Example, for $f(D = -1) = 0$, below sum equals LHS
$\\f(0.0) + f(0.0) + f(1.0) ≈ 1.167
\\f(0.0) + f(0.5) + f(0.5) ≈ 1.256
\\f(0.2) + f(0.3) + f(0.5) ≈ 1.277
\\f(0.3) + f(0.3) + f(0.4) ≈ 1.284
\\f(1/3) + f(1/3) + f(1/3) = 9/7 ≈ 1.286 ≤ 4/3
$
With above insight, proof is trivial, $A=B=C=x \;,\; D=-3x$
CAS> factor(3*f(x) + f(-3x) - 4/3)

-4*x^2*(x-1)^2 / ((1+3*x^2)*(3+x^2))

